# maven and eclipse builds differently the same project

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss, ear

I have a java ear maven project.

When I publish the ear to jboss7 via eclipse it generates an ear and deploys it to jboss.

But when I manually run a maven build of the same project I get a different ear in size and also the name is different.

When eclise builds the project when executing "publish to server", doesnt it use the same build as maven?

I use eclipse juno and maven3. I'm new to maven.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses the .classpath to package the ear that gets deployed to jboss. When you do a manual maven build it is using the pom.xml file to package the ear. If those aren't in sync you could get differences in your ears.

Comment: you could try running mvn eclipse:eclipse from the command line. Also, the m2eclipse plugin is a useful tool for keeping the 2 environments in sync.

Comment: We have the project in git and I have imported it in eclipse via 'import maven project' I have m2eclipse plugin installed in eclipse. 
I tryed mvn eclipse:eclipse but the build still differs